# Upload csv file to REST API with R

Tags: r, csv, curl, rcurl

I want to upload a csv file to a REST API.
The API is accessible via an URL like

```
http://sampledomain.com/api/data/?key=xxx
```

A provided sample curl call looks as following:

```
 curl --form "file=@my_data.zip" \
     "http://sampledomain.com/api/data/?key=xxx"
```

How can I translate this call into R?
I heard of the RCurl package, but can´t figure out how to use it in this case.

Regards

Comment: It's not the most elegant, but you could always call curl with ``system``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure RCurl will handle it as you can see from the limit on the [first page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/RCurl.pdf).

> Limitations One doesn't yet have full control over the contents of a
>   POST form such as specifying files, content type. Error handling uses
>   a single global variable at present.

However, another package from Hadley that might solve your problem [httr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf)

```
POST("http://sampledomain.com/api/data/?key=xxx", body = list(y = upload_file(system.file("my_data.zip"))))
```

Comment: hi, this seems to work with single file, how do we add multiple files in the body ? I also have a token that need to be sent in the upload request.