# Uploading CSV file in an API using R

Tags: r

Can some one help with the codes for connecting an API using R and uploading file consisting of around 2k records into the API using R

I tried the below codes but not helping out:

```
apiurl <- "https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/match/file"
Records <- "C:\\Users\\U6028364\\Downloads\\Organization_input_template_with_examples.csv
  resp <- POST(apiurl,body=list(

                    addressFile=upload_file(Records),
                    Content-Type="multipart",


      ))

stop_for_status(resp)
get_data <- content(resp,"text")
```

Thanks
Gautam

Comment: your question is very unclear and open ended

Comment: What issues are you specifically having? What have you tried? ([Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53741261/edit) your question)

Comment: googling your question exactly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733571/upload-csv-file-to-rest-api-with-r
does this resolve it?

Comment: No John that is not helping out.Below is the error I got when running the above code:Error: Unauthorized (HTTP 401)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to explain the following with a paragraph in a comment would be painful, so take a look at:

```
api_url <- "https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/match/file"

records <- "C:\\Users\\U6028364\\Downloads\\Organization_input_template_with_examples.csv"

httr::POST(
  url = api_url,
  body = list(
    addressFile = httr::upload_file(records),
  ),
  encode = "multipart"
) -> resp

httr::stop_for_status(resp)

get_data <- content(resp, "text")
```

the only real change is that you need to use the `encode` parameter (also, you missed a `"` in your question code).

I don't have access to the TR API so I can't test this. However, https://docs-developers.thomsonreuters.com/1544617757924/45690/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=PermID%20Service/PermID%20APIs%20User%20Guide.1.27.html says this is the `curl` command line to do what you are trying to do:

```
curl -X POST https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/match/file 
     -H "Content-Type: multipart/form data" 
     -H "x-openmatch-numberOfMatchesPerRecord: 1" 
     -H "x-openmatch-datatype: Organization" 
     -H "X-AG-Access-Token: <token>" 
     -F file=@OrgRecords.csv
```

You're missing some things if that is the case and also using an improper `body`, so this might work better:

```
httr::POST(
  url = api_url,
  httr::add_headers(
    `X-AG-Access-Token` = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_WHICH_YOU_RLY_SHLDNT_PUT_DIRECTLY_IN_R_SCRIPTS"
  )
  body = list(
    file = httr::upload_file(records)
  ),
  encode = "multipart"
) -> resp
```

I have no idea if the other "openmatch" headers are required or not.

Comment: I tried with your above codes but it is giving the below error:Error in list(file = httr::upload_file(records), ) : argument 2 is empty

Comment: i originally had `httr::verbose()` as a parameter after `httr::upload_file(records)` and forgot to remove the comma. try it now with that comma removed

Comment: This is the error it is giving : Error in as.request(config) : object 'httr' not found

Comment: And I missed a `:` on one of the fully qualified function references (I realize the error was my typo but both the `,` and the missing `:` are basic R errors that would be good to be familiar with in terms of you being able to work with R…I'm assuming you're really new to R as a result).

Comment: Yes I am pretty new to R.I didnt quite understand on where did you missed a  :

Comment: the `records` in your case is single .csv file. How do we pass all files in a folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is what i tried to do but it is giving error as: Error in as.request(config) : object 'httr' not found

```
httr::POST(
  url = api_url,
  httr:add_headers(
    X-AG-Access-Token : "abcd"

  ),
  body = list(
    file = httr::upload_file(records)
  ),
  encode = "multipart"
) -> resp
```